# Having Time Delay on LiveChart input

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to ask - Is the LiveChart suitable apply for Oscilloscope on C# WPF?

Because currently I'm facing some issue regarding the input time delay. The input time delay (on the right side of the waveform 32.44) is not synchronize to other chart when I open more than 2 chart.

May need your guys help and provide some idea on it.

I'm not sure is it because of LiveChart library limitation or maybe other problem.

You may refer to below image

Input time delay at `32.44`

[image]

You may view my code for chart implementation on below.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var mapper = Mappers.Xy<MeasureModel>()
            .X(model => model.DateTime.Ticks)   //use DateTime.Ticks as X
            .Y(model => model.Value);           //use the value property as Y

        //lets save the mapper globally.
        Charting.For<MeasureModel>(mapper);

        //the values property will store our values array
        ChartValues1 = new ChartValues<MeasureModel>();
        ChartValues2 = new ChartValues<MeasureModel>();
        ChartValues3 = new ChartValues<MeasureModel>();
        ChartValues4 = new ChartValues<MeasureModel>();

        //lets set how to display the X Labels
        DateTimeFormatter = value => new DateTime((long)value).ToString("mm:ss");

        //AxisStep forces the distance between each separator in the X axis
        V.AxisStep = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).Ticks;

        //AxisUnit forces lets the axis know that we are plotting seconds
        //this is not always necessary, but it can prevent wrong labeling
        V.AxisUnit = TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond;

        A.SetAxisLimits(DateTime.Now);

        A.IsReading1 = false;
        B.IsReading2 = false;
        C.IsReading3 = false;
        D.IsReading4 = false;

        DataContext = this;

        Screen1.UpdaterState = UpdaterState.Paused;
        Screen2.UpdaterState = UpdaterState.Paused;
        Screen3.UpdaterState = UpdaterState.Paused;
        Screen4.UpdaterState = UpdaterState.Paused;
        initializeComboBox();

    }


    private void Read1()
    {
        while (A.IsReading1)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            var now = DateTime.Now;

            ChartValues1.Add(new MeasureModel
            {
                DateTime = now,
                Value = A.result1
            });

            A.SetAxisLimits(now);

            //lets only use the last 150 values
            if (ChartValues1.Count > 150) ChartValues1.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }


    private void Read2()
    {
        while (B.IsReading2)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            var now = DateTime.Now;

            ChartValues2.Add(new MeasureModel
            {
                DateTime = now,
                Value = B.result2
            });

            B.SetAxisLimits(now);

            //lets only use the last 150 values
            if (ChartValues2.Count > 150) ChartValues2.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }

    private void StartScope()
    {
        if (A.IsReading1 && A.screen1)
        {
            A.result1 = 0;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(Read1);
            Screen1.UpdaterState = UpdaterState.Running;
            A.screen1 = false;
        }

        else if (B.IsReading2 && B.screen2)
        {
            B.result2 = 0;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(Read2);
            Screen2.UpdaterState = UpdaterState.Running;
            B.screen2 = false;
        }
    }


public class Screen1 // Separate Class for Chart 1
{
    public bool IsReading1 { get; set; }
    public int result1 { get; set; }
    public bool screen1 { get; set; }

    public double _axisMax;
    public double _axisMin;

    public double AxisMax
    {
        get { return _axisMax; }
        set
        {
            _axisMax = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AxisMax");
        }
    }
    public double AxisMin
    {
        get { return _axisMin; }
        set
        {
            _axisMin = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AxisMin");
        }
    }

    public void SetAxisLimits(DateTime now)
    {
        AxisMax = now.Ticks + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).Ticks; // lets force the axis to be 1 second ahead
        AxisMin = now.Ticks - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8).Ticks; // and 8 seconds behind
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion

}


public class Screen2 // Separate Class for Chart 2
{

    public bool IsReading2 { get; set; }
    public int result2 { get; set; }
    public bool screen2 { get; set; }

    public double _axisMax;
    public double _axisMin;
    public double AxisMax
    {
        get { return _axisMax; }
        set
        {
            _axisMax = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AxisMax");
        }
    }
    public double AxisMin
    {
        get { return _axisMin; }
        set
        {
            _axisMin = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AxisMin");
        }
    }

    public void SetAxisLimits(DateTime now)
    {
        AxisMax = now.Ticks + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).Ticks; // lets force the axis to be 1 second ahead
        AxisMin = now.Ticks - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8).Ticks; // and 8 seconds behind
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Comment: I guess you mean the x-axis are not vertically aligned. Can you please post your chart implementation?

Comment: Hi BionicCode, Thanks for the reply. Yes.The x-axis are not vertically aligned. You may view my code for chart implementation on below.

Comment: @BionicCode May I know got any finding from your side?

Comment: If you want to add information to your question, then don't post it as an answer, please. Click on the _edit_  button beneath your question to edit it. I have pasted your answer into your original question. Please delete your answer.

Comment: Apologize for the mistake I have make due to this was my first time posting a question on StackOverflow. Thanks a lot for helping me edit.

Answer (score 0):

The horizontal offset you are observing, is relaed to the unit of the x-axis. Your `DateTime` values are not rounded e.g. to seconds. You always take the complete timestamp including milliseconds. When isolating the seconds the timestamps of the different charts do match. But when looking at the milliseconds the don't. It's quite obvious when comparing the yellow series to the blue: the timestamps of the yellow series fall right in between the x values blue series, creating an "offset", which is absolutely correct, but not desired. Replacing x-axis unit of `DateTime` with a fixed transit time interval (e.g. 5, 10, 15) will fix this.

The current implementation does not mimic how an oscilloscope works. You are not showing time stamps on the x-axis or absolute values on the y-axis. You just provide constant grid or a scale to measure the signal. The weight of the grid's interval (both axis) is customizable by the user. E.g. each horizontal interval is 5ms and vertical interval 1 Volts. So you don't need the timestamp (`DateTime`) to draw the signal, but the transit time (`TimeSpan`). You have to emulate a trigger to select  the proper range of values in order to provide a stable snapshot of the signal. So the number of values to take to plot the screen depends on the current time base. The number is not fixed e.g. the last 150 values. You can use the transit time or calculated frequency to scale the signal to fit the current selected time base of the viewport grid. Let's say your viewport has a 10*8 grid and the user sets the time base to 5ms, then you have to plot 50ms of the signal and label the x-axis 5ms, 10ms, 15ms, ....

Your programming style is not object oriented. You should either use inheritance to encapsulate common code inside a base class. So instead of having two classes `Screen1` and `Screen2`, you should have a single class `Screen` which has all the common logic and then derive `Screen1` and `Screen2` from it and add some specific features. Or, if they don't have specific features, then have a single class `Screen`. You then create two or *n* instances of this class

```
var screen1 = new Screen();
var screen2 = new Screen();
```

Always avoid duplicate code. Same applies to `Read1` and `Read2`. Both contain the exact same code. You should merge both methods and also read channels in parallel:

```
// Read each channel in a separate thread
private void ReadChannels()
{
  Task.Run(() => ReadChannel(this.ChartValues1, this.ScreenA));
  Task.Run(() => ReadChannel(this.ChartValues2, this.ScreenB));
  Task.Run(() => ReadChannel(this.ChartValues3, this.ScreenC));
}

private void ReadChannel(ChartValues<MeasureModel> chartValues, Screen screen)
{
  while (screen.IsReading1)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    var now = DateTime.Now;

    chartValues.Add(new MeasureModel
    {
      DateTime = now,
      Value = screen.result1
    });

    screen.SetAxisLimits(now);

    //lets only use the last 150 values
    if (chartValues.Count > 150) 
      chartValues.RemoveAt(0);
  }
}
```

I recommend to take a look at [LiveCharts Geared](https://lvcharts.net/licensing/pricing) as it boasts itself to be high performant in live plotting scenarios.
Also live charts has some limitations. You can't change the offset of the plot. This is a basic requirement for an oscilloscope in order to freely align the signal with the grid in order to visually interpret the signal. You would have to implement it yourself. You can draw multiple series into a single chart, but you can't stack them.

Comment: From the statement of "Replacing x-axis unit of DateTime with a fixed transit time interval (e.g. 5, 10, 15) will fix this", may I know this is the line code I need to change ? Possible to show me some example on it? Is this the line code I need to change? "V.AxisUnit = TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond;"?

           For the programming style, previously was combined into single class but that time I suspect the delay issue might be came from single class, therefore, I separate out. But unfortunately, it doesn't help at all. The delays was still there.